# What is the appropriate solution for os?

Tags: java, operating-system, windows-xp

Java software is not working in ms xp OS service pack 2. What are the problem that would change my OS to allow working of java ?

Comment: what problem do you have, what type of error

Comment: Update to a newer version of java if the one installed is outdated.

Comment: Have you installed Java? When did it stop working, or was it ever working?

Comment: Yes, i installed, but when i knew its not working, i just removed sun folder from my c drive and installed JDK, but after that it's not working, the error shows is file path c:\\mycomputer...etc its not responding , am really in struggle, i couldnt work on java am un satisfied with this.. Should i change my os xp to win 7?? suggestions please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question there is plenty of possible answers.

First: You have to download and install JDK (or at least JRE) in order to run jar files.
Download and entire installation process is described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

**EDIT 1:**
Regarding to your questions in comments I am edited this answer.

> Okay sir Bosko Mijin, thanks for your kind help.. how to check java is
>   working?? and should i change my OS to win 7? please give suggestions.

You should to check is JDK installed on your machine. Fastest way is that you run following commands (noted below) in command promt to check version and compiler. 
Checking Java version: `java -version`
Checking Java compiler: `javac -version`
If there is installed JVM (attention: not Microsoft JVM) then you have to check environment variables and ensure that `JAVA_HOME` variable is set and it is in you `PATH` also.

You can do check this with following command: `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

If you have installed Microsoft JVM, I suggest to change OS (easier way, but clean) because Microsoft JVM supports Java up to v1.1 (it is very very old!). Harder way is that you get old versions of JVM and try to install them to your XP, but there is questionable are that packages 'young enough'.

FYI: Win7 have no such problems with JVM.

If you have Microsoft JVM, it would be great that you read this [link](http://marksxp.mvps.org/WindowsXP/java.php). It will help you to decide what next.

Regarding to OS, I am not good person for this type questions because I like Unix/Linux systems (I am using them for long time ago) and I am afraid that my answer regarding this part will be very 'primary opinion based'.

Anyway, I wish you to solve this quickly. Best luck.

Comment: Yes, i installed, but when i knew its not working, i just removed sun folder from my c drive and installed JDK, but after that it's not working, the error shows is file path c:\\mycomputer...etc its not responding , am really in struggle, i couldnt work on java am un satisfied with this.. Should i change my os xp to win 7?? suggestions please

Comment: Regarding to fact that you are removed sun folder and installed JDK, I suggest you that perform check for environment variables. I suppose that JDK/JRE is not pointed well. Note that there can be a lot of possible solutions, I am only guessing what can produce your problem.

Comment: Okay sir Bosko Mijin, thanks for your kind help.. how to check java is working?? and should i change my OS to win 7? please give suggestions.

Comment: Thank you sir, I changed my os successfully.. bosko mijin..